# Understanding Kolmogorov Extension Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation

I'm following [these notes](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/lecture-5-the-daniell-kolmogorov-existence-theorem/) where the author proves the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem. In order to do so, he uses an auxiliary lemma to construct a sequence of compact sets $K_{n} \subset B_{n}$ such that $K_{n+1}\subset K_{n}\times \mathbb{R}$ and:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu_{n}(K_{n}) \ge \frac{\epsilon}{2} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
Then, he states:

> "Since $K_{n}$ is non-empty, we pick $(x_{1}^{n},...,x_{n}^{n})\in K_{n}$ [...]"

My problem is: where (\ref{1}) being used in the proof? Does it assure that each $K_{n} \neq \emptyset$? How come?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Just forgot to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, note that $\mu_n(K_n)\geq \epsilon/2>0$. On the other hand $\mu_n(\emptyset)=0$. Hence, $K_n\neq \emptyset$.